# Generate a radius for a point, in order to count how many times a line passes through that radius

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, algorithm

I am working on a project where I have to count the number of lines passing near a point. I plan to generate a radius around each point, since the lines do not cross the point, but pass close to it, but I don't know how to do this in QGIS. The project is in AutoCAD, but I have to work in QGIS, since I have to georeference the project, besides doing the above mentioned.

Each line passes at different distances in relation to the point, so if it is possible to generate different radii it could be better. If it is not possible, it is not a problem since I could count by hand.

Answer (score 2):

You can count automatically for each point how many lines pass nearby, defined by a maximum distance, with QGIS expressions and function `overlay_nearest()`. Use the following expression, e.g. with Field calculator to create a new attribute field:

```
array_length(
    overlay_nearest (
        'line',  -- replace with the name of your line layer
        $id,
        limit:=-1,
        max_distance:=24  -- replace with the distance you want 
    )
)
```

*The expression returns the no. of lines inside the red circle (here created for visualization purpose only): 6 lines are within a maximum distance of 24 meters:*
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do this for multiple circles? the lines are technically continuous but they pass through near multiple points, hence multiple circles.

Comment: This automatically works for all points of a layer: each point is evaluated separately